# is it possible to have a indicator in web page scroll view - I mean I want a holder/button that I can hold and scroll up/down?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview, xcode4.3

I want to have a scroll holder in webview - basically I have a UIWebView in which I am opening  a pdf - this pdf have more than 100 pages so I don't want user to keep scrolling till his finger starts paining but looking for a scroll holder to quickly scroll up/down...

any ideas ? thought ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: create a button.. to move to next page.. your problem will get solved..

Comment: but this still require a user to press button 50 timed yo go to page 50... looking for a fancy scroll holder...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate view along the side of the UIWebView and handle touch events on it. You can also add a UISlider to handle the pagination.

Comment: Sound like a solution -- but how do I link the pdf with UISlider ?
is there a way to link PDF Pagenumber with UISlider ? (I have already pulled my half of my hairs trying finding this... no luck still..)